# Creating spy for HttpClient post creates a return value error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I have a service that takes an `HttpClient` service as a value, I would like to spy on the `post` method of that class so I created a spy that looks like this:

```
spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and.returnValue(() => new Subject<any>().asObservable());
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Argument of type '() => Observable<any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Observable<unknown>'.
  Type '() => Observable<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<unknown>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 6 more.
```

Here is the spec that it comes from:

```
describe('GraphQLClientService', () => {
  let service: GraphQLClientService;
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let postSpy: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    httpClient = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', []);
    postSpy = spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and.returnValue(() => new Subject<any>().asObservable());
    service = new GraphQLClientService(httpClient);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you spying `httpClinet`? you suppose to provide `httpClintModule` in your .spec providers with mock service.

Comment: @KamranKhatti Could you post an example?

Comment: @KamranKhatti The angular website does it the way that I did it: https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#services-with-dependencies

Comment: It never did same, its injecting an other custom service to master service the httpClient is not a custom service we inject it to read method and no need to mock it instead of it mock the method in which we use httpclient get, post etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a function that returns an Observable instead of only an Observable

```
postSpy = spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and.returnValue(new Subject<any>().asObservable());
```

or

```
postSpy = spyOn(httpClient, 'post').and.returnValue(of({}));
```